# CSS :target + scrollbars

Tags: css

Can I hide the scrollbar when the popup target is active? Only css.

```css
div {display: none}
#popup:target{display: block;}
```

```html
<a href="#popup">Popup</a>
<a href="#">Del</a>

<div id="popup">
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
content<br>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5bjLwc1e/

Comment: where is the scrollbar?

Comment: How has this been upvoted twice - it's not even clear what the OP is after as there is no scrollbar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5bjLwc1e/

Comment: So what do you want to happen with the overflowing content if you cannot scroll it?  Are they the only styles on the popup (ie is it  position fixed or anything or just relative to the links like you have it in the example?)

Comment: Please take the time to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide a **clear problem statement** with a [mcve] that replicates your issue

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter I think. What I want to do is that when the #popup:target is active, the BODY, maybe HTML tag will be {overflow: hidden}

I tried

```
#popup:target:active + body {overflow: hidden;}
#popup:target ~ body {overflow: hidden;}
```

but nothing.

I did this with jQuery, it works well! But can I do it with pure CSS? Ty

```
var url = window.location.hash;
$(function(){
  if (url.substring(url.indexOf('#'))){
    $("html, body").css({
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: '100%'
});
  }
  $("#isnt-scroll").click(function() {
    $("html, body").css({
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: '100%'
});
    }); 
});
```